# Homology Poincare Homology Sphere by Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am working through some pages of Dale Rolfsen, Knots and Links, AMS Chelsea Publishing, 2003, in order to understand Dehn approach to the original Poincaré conjecture.   To be concrete with what I am struggling at I insert two pictures:

[image: dehn1]

[image: dehn2]

I was able to check that $Q$ is connected, closed 3-manifold. But I am stack with the computation of homology using Mayer-Vietoris.

My first attempt was to use as subsets: $\mathbb{S}^3-\text{Int} N$ and $\mathbb{S}^1 \times D^2$ but their interiors don't cover the space $Q$. Then I was trying to modify that subsets so they cover $Q$, but I haven't found the appropriate way to do that in order to have easy computations with Mayer-Vietoris afterwards. Any suggestion or idea?

Note: I don't know specific techniques to deal with 3-manifolds.

Thanks in advance!  Any help would be appreciated and even more if it involves full explanations!

Comment: Just thicken those sets a little bit.

Comment: Just thicken them a little bit as Mike miller says. If I remember, there is a statement in Hatcher about Mayer Vietoris of two sets whose interiors don't cover the space, but the intersection has a neighborhood that retracts to the intersection. Something along the lines of "the following is convenient in many applications"

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Just soon after @MikeMiller pointed out that I managed to solve it. Thanks anyway!